# SWRevealViewController Table not Displaying Static Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, menu

What am i doing wrong with my table view when implementing SWRevalViewController?

I've followed all the tutorials and as far i know everything is configured correctly.  I've got the tableview displaying but none of the cells are showing.
They are just static labels.

I've tried, a normal viewcontroller with a tableview and cells added, and I've tried a table view controller as per the images below.  i can only assume that I'm doing something wrong with how I've populated the table or maybe something to do with the prototype cell, which even if i delete it I'm still left with "prototype cell" as something of a header. (see last image)

thanks for any ideas, been staring at this for a day now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the type of your TableView? is it static or dynamic?
if you want to show, what you made in storyboard, you need to make it static

Comment: thank you I'm a muppet...  i forgot to switch the content from dynamic to static in property inspector!